# Coordinar barra lateral y navegador co bootstrap

Tags: html5, css3, aplicación-web, web, bootstrap-3

Buenas!

Lo primero de todo soy un supernoob con páginas web y he tomado la mala decisión de usar bootstrap en mi primer proyecto de la universidad, así que agradecería todo consejo que podáis darme :3

Estoy haciendo una plantilla de la barra de navegación y la barra lateral y quiero que estén un poco coordinadas.

Primero he creado una fila donde esta colocada la barra de navegación y la he dividido en dos columnas, una de tamaño md-2 y otra de md-10, en la pequeña he puesto el header de la barra y en la grande los botones.

Para el resto de la página he hecho otra fila y la he dividido de la misma forma que la anterior. En la pequeña esta situada la barra lateral y en la grande el contenido principal de las páginas.

Haciendo esto he conseguido que parezca que las dos barras se unen en el header y le da un aspecto bastante estético a mi parecer.

El problema es que estoy corriegiendo la posición de algunos elementos de bootstrap cambiando los elementos margin y padding de algunos divs para conseguir que todo cuadre como quiero, pero claro según el navegador y tamaño de pantalla la posición que he puesto no es la misma y se descuadra.

[image: Plantilla]

Como puedo hacer para que algunos divs donde pongo botones, contenido o lo que sea se quede siempre en la misma posición? (pegado a un lateral o top). He probado varias formas que he encontrado por internet pero siempre se descuadra algo y es un poco frustrante porque pierdo más tiempo colocando cosas que pensando y haciendo la página.

Aquí dejo el código: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Pablovg/pen/gmELNy)

Utilizo bootstrap 3.3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar los siguientes códigos en css.

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
```

Uno hace que sea absoluto como dice, e independiente de lo que haya, siempre se quedara allí. z-index define en que "capa" esta, o sea, si quieres que este por encima de todo coloca 9999, si algo estará por sobre este, ese elemento debe tener un z-index superior.

Espero que te ayuden estos códigos y éxito con tu proyecto :D

Answer (score 0):

Amigo recuerda que siempre los row de boostrap siempre tienen 12 celdas es decir.
en un

```
<div class="row">
```

maximo de 12 celdas si quieres tener mas de 12 crea otros row .
aparte de eso te recomiendo que leas la documentacion de boostrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

recuerda que tambien en un `<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">`  puedes colocar la diferente diferencias de un pantalla.

en tu codigo ya lo modifique :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWoRPg

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="inicio.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-full">

        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container margin-left-nav">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        <!-- Navbar brand (Brainiac) y botón colapsable -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">

                            <!-- Navbar botones -->
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav horizontal mar-left">
                                <li><a href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="miembros.html">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <!-- Navbar derecho (Registro, Login) -->
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right horizontal">

                                <!-- Registro -->
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Registrarse<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-width">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <h3><b>Registro</b></h3></div>
                                            <form>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña">
                                                </div>

                                                <!-- Botón Registrase -->
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                                                            <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-info" value="Registrarse">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <!-- Inicio de sesión -->
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Iniciar sesión <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-width">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <h3><b>Inicio de sesión</b></h3></div>
                                            <form>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="username">Usuario</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                                                            <input type="checkbox">
                                                            <label for="remember">Recordarme</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-5 pull-right">
                                                            <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Log In">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                                <a href="#" class="forgot-password">Olvidaste la contraseña?</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="hidden" class="hide" name="token" id="token" value="a465a2791ae0bae853cf4bf485dbe1b6">
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <section class="container-full">

        <!-- Main page -->
        <div class="row" id="full-page">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                <div class="profile-sidebar">

                    <!-- User picture -->
                    <div class="profile-userpic">
                        <img src="img/Otros/noUserPic.png" class="img-responsive img-circle border" alt="foto">
                    </div>

                    <!-- Sidebar title -->
                    <div class="profile-user">
                        <div class="profile-name">User</div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Sidebar menu -->
                    <nav class="profile-menu">
                        <ul class="nav navbar vertical">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Perfil</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></i> Estadísticas</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> Trofeos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i> Ayuda</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-2">

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(239, 244, 246);
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.mar-left {
    margin-left: -13px !important;
}

ul.navbar-right {
    /*margin-right: -15.45vw !important;*/
    margin-right: -8.5vw !important;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {

}

.row {

}

.margin-left-nav {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

ul.dropdown-width {
    width: 300px;
}

.navbar .nav>li.dropdown.open.active>a:hover,
.navbar .nav>li.dropdown.open>a,
li a:hover,
li.active>a {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: rgb(10, 66, 117) !important;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(10, 66, 117) !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

li.active>a {
    background-color: rgb(10, 66, 117) !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #5b9bd1 !important;
}

ul.horizontal li {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

ul.horizontal li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}


/*.center {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}*/


/*.vertical-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}*/

.border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}


/*----- Sidebar -----*/

.profile-sidebar {
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
    height: 92.5vh;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.profile-userpic {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.profile-userpic img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
}

.profile-user {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.profile-name {
    color: #93a3b5;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.profile-menu {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.profile-menu ul li a {
    color: #93a3b5;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-left: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul.vertical li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.profile-menu ul li a i {
    margin-right: 9px;
    font-size: 14px;
}


/*----- End Sidebar -----*/

#full-page {
    background-color: rgb(239, 244, 246);
    width: 100vw;
}

#header-content {
    height: 43.5vh;
}

.lma-content {
    height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sí, se lo que me habéis respondido y he probado varias veces, (Como estoy aún por la primera entraga aún no tengo que adapatar la página a dispositivos móviles y demás) a lo que me refiero es a que  bootstrap tiene margin y padding por defecto en algunos de sus elementos, y los estoy contrarrestado para colocarlos justo donde quiero.

La solución ideal para mí sería decirle a un elemento ponte a la derecha del todo sin importar el padding y margin por defecto, pero no consigo que se quede en su lugar porque tengo que corregir esos campos constantemente.

Comment: Deberías expresar esto como un comentario sobre la respuesta  a la que te quieres referir, puesto que no corresponde como una respuesta. Una vez expreses tu comentario entonces elimina este aporte.